# Building an Android ROS app in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ros

I have ros, rosjava, and android_core on my Ubuntu machine, as well as Eclipse and the Android SDK and ADT. Now, I'm trying to create an android application using the following instructions but I'm having trouble:
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/getting_started.html#getting-started

After copying the android_tutorial_pubsub into another folder and trying to open it with Eclipse I get a bunch of unrecognized packages. Eclipse doesn't know where to find ros classes (such as RosActivity) and I'm not sure how to import them. I tried importing the android_core as per: http://ros.org/wiki/android_core#Eclipse_configuration and that creates another project called MasterChooser that I can then link to the pubsub tutorial to fix some of the referencing errors, but the projects (pubsub and MasterChooser) still don't recognize certain files that are in rosjava. For this I tried File->Import->General->File System and then manually select the rosjava packages but that still leaves some issues.

Overall I feel there must be a simpler way to make the android app (pubsub) reference both android_core and rosjava, but my lack of experience in ros and in eclipse are making this hard. In short, I really just want to be able to run the tutorial apps (like pubsub) from Eclipse into my android device.

Comment: Better, try Android Studio

Comment: @Frankie well no because it is in pre-release :-p i.e. not for noobs!